# Mongoose Populate with express res.json() breaks

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I'm selecting **Activities** from the mongodb and populating **User** for each.

```
var query = Activity.find(query).populate("user");
return query.sort({created:"desc"}).exec(function(err, activities) {
    debugger;
    if (!err) {
        return res.json(activities);
    } else {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
});
```

As you can see I have a **debugger;** breakpoint is there, When I'm pring **activities** it prints an array of activities with the user object populated.
Also when I'm calling something like **activities[0].toJSON()** I get everything good!

But the response comes back with the **user** property empty !

I looked into the source of **express.response.json(OBJ)** and saw this line:

`var body = JSON.stringify(val, replacer, spaces);`
*val is my activities*

When calling `JSON.stringify(activities)` it will create a json with an empty user field.. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try the `lean` option.](http://ilee.co.uk/mongoose-documents-and-jsonstringify/) That gives back plain JS objects with no mongoose weirdness. Also, your error handling seems a little awkward, can be simplified.

```
var query = Activity.find(query).populate("user");
query.sort({created:"desc"}).lean().exec(function(err, activities) {
    if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
    res.json(activities);
});
```

I would go even further, not hard-coding error sending in routes but simply passing along via `if (err) return next(err)` to error-handling middleware defined elsewhere in your app. You can still set the status, then use detection in your middleware, something like this:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    err.status = err.status || 500;
    res.status(err.status).json(err);
});
```

Comment: Great answer ! the **lean()** actually worked. Also the middleware you wrote isn't complete right ?
and it's a bug in express? or in mongoose ? what's happening there exactly ?

Comment: "and it's a bug in express? or in mongoose ?" — not sure what "it" you are referring to; your original problem must have been an issue with Mongoose's `toObject` & `toJSON` methods (both of which are called when you `res.json` the activities. Not a bug, but an issue of how deep Mongoose goes when objectifying populated documents.

The middleware is complete insofar as it `res.json`'s any `err`s passed to `next` in routes. If you want to set the status, then in a route you could do like so: `if (err) { err.status = 404; return next(err); }`.